# Increase font size of web pages on iPad?

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari

Can you increase the font size for web pages on an iPad using the default safari browser?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202828

Comment: That doesnt change the font size for safari.

Comment: http://marcos.kirsch.mx/2012/04/29/font-size-bookmarklets/ this should do the trick